# Создание custom token на Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Делаю клиентское приложение на Android. В качестве сервера Firebase.
При первом запуске пользователь вводит почту и пароль. 
Как сделать дальнейший вход по токену (методом signInWithCustomToken())?.
Или как его сгенерировать на сервере?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, после создания юзера с мылом и паролем или нового входа по этим данным Firebase сам хранит сесиию (токен) и при следующем запуске приложения, если его данные не чистили, юзер будет автоматически залогинен. Т.е. вам не надо что-то вручную хранить и вручную авторизовывать юзера при каждом запуске.

А `signInWithCustomToken` это вообще про другое - это для создания возможности логина через неподдерживаемые по умолчанию провайдеры. Например `ВК`. В таких случаях вы должны на своём сервере сгенерить ID юзера и получить по этому ID токен токен от Firebase через Rest запрос или специальной админской либой, предварительно авторизовав сервер в проекте Firebase.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, все встало на свои места.